# Problems with Python syntax and Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, control-flow

I am developing a game and have encountered a few unsolvable (by me at least) issues.

Problems that I have with my code are:

1. When asking if you want to save a screenshot, only inputting anything which can be translated, by the `lower()` method, into either `"yes"` or `"no"` will be accepted despite the `or` statement - one of the conditions in that code block is `if save_option.lower() == ("yes" or "y"):` and it will only accept `"yes"`, or else the condition is evaluated as `False`. I don't know why this is.
2. When rendering the introduction to the game in `def introduction():`, for some reason, each surface object is getting drawn twice. Here is what it looks like:[image]
   However, when I increase the pixels moved every frame to 60, this happens:
   [image]
3. When '*deliver all his presents*' reaches the top of the screen, `introduction()` ends and the main game loop starts. **I** can see any logic error relating to this in this bit of code:

   while not pygame.sprite.Group.has(intro_story_surface_objects):
   for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == QUIT or event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key 
   == K_ESCAPE:
   destroy()

   ```
   DS.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))
   pygame.draw.rect(DS, (0, 0, 0, 50), (0, DISPLAY_HEIGHT - 200, DISPLAY_WIDTH, 200), 0) # (screen, color, (x,y,width,height), thickness)

   count = 0
   for line in intro_story_surface_objects:

       line_x_y = (intro_story_surface_objects[line].rect.x, intro_story_surface_objects[line].rect.y)
       intro_story_sprite_group.draw(DS)
       intro_story_surface_objects[line].rect.y -= 60 # intro_story_surface_objects[line].speed

       if intro_story_surface_objects[line].rect.y + intro_story_surface_objects[line].rect.height < 0:
           intro_story_surface_objects[line].kill()
           # print("Kill")
           line_kills += 1

           if line_kills == len(intro_story_surface_objects):
               return


   pygame.display.update()
   clock.tick(30)
   ```

Thanks again, in advance for trying to help.

From Kiran

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Also, make sure that your code is complete and verifiable, so that we can run and test it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is there anyone else that can help with pygame issues or even control flow as this might be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question 2.

I still need 2 other questions answered apart from this.

When the code is executed, the text looks like it is being drawn twice. The problem is that every time that the x and y coordinates for each line of text are changed, the WHOLE list of lines what being drawn twice.

Just a little accident. My code was meant to be structured like this:

- `while there are lines of text:`
- `draw all the lines in this command - intro_story_sprite_group.draw(DS)`
- `loop through each line:`
- `Change its (x, y)`

Not do this:

- `while there are lines of text:`
- `loop through each line:`
- `draw all the lines in this command - intro_story_sprite_group.draw(DS)`
- `Change its (x, y)`

Please don't forget that I still need 2 more questions answered!
Thanks for your help,

Kiran

Answer (score 3):

1. For problem one. Try:
   `if save_option.lower() in ['yes', 'y']:`

What your or statement within the parens is saying is: If the first value evaluates to false, compare against the second. Since the string `'yes'` is always `True` `save_option.lower()` is never compared against `'y'`.

I can't help with the rest of it unfortunately. I haven't used Pygame. Good luck though! And happy gaming.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Harry MW.

Comment: At least you helped me solve one problem. I really appreciate it. :-)